# I want to return a variable Result at Class (Fraction *)

Tags: objective-c

```
- (Fraction *)add:(Fraction *)addFra {

    Fraction *numerator1 = [[Fraction alloc]initWithFraction:[self initWithNumerator:self.num]];

    Fraction *numerator2 = [[Fraction alloc]initWithFraction:[self initWithNumerator:addFra.num]];

    Fraction *denominator1 = [[Fraction alloc]initWithFraction:[self initWithDenominator:self.den]];

    Fraction *denominator2 = [[Fraction alloc]initWithFraction:[self initWithDenominator:addFra.den]];

    Fraction *result = (numerator1 * denominator2) + (numerator2 * denominator1);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't have operator overloading, so those maths operations will have to be implemented using methods:

```
Fraction *result = [[numerator1 multiply:denominator2] add:[numerator2 multiply:denominator1]];
```

I haven't shown the implementation of `multiply:` or `add:` because, to be frank, I can't be bothered to see how to do it properly.

Comment: thank your sharing, you can do it below my code above.